# How to view your own calendar availability status?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2019

This seems like a simple question (and it is) but I could not find an answer to this anywhere, nor any indication that it can be done.

In Outlook, is there any way to view your own availability status?

By this, I mean a calendar view formatted the way you like it (e.g. Day, Week, next 7 days, month) that, rather than showing the details of events, only shows if you are busy, free, tentative, away, etc. during those times?

I know others can do this when they view your shared calendar, but this is not about calendar sharing. The application here would be for perhaps taking a screen capture and sharing that via email. That's why I would like to be able to do this myself.

I'd rather not create a dummy account and share a calendar with it just to gain access to this view. It seems calendar owners should be able to have it also.

On the View tab, there is a "Schedule View" option:

[image]

However, it's basically useless, as it does this:

[image]

Clearly, there is no way to indicate your availability this way for more than a few hours, and you can't use this Schedule View feature with **Next 7 days**, which is pretty much what I exclusively use. The way this Schedule View is implemented, you can't see more than a few hours; just to share 2 days of availability, I would need a 4 feet long monitor just to be able to do a screen capture.

Is there an actual separate layer that allows details to be omitted from calendars that would only show availability?

Answer (score 0):

No option to realize this, but it would basically be the same as naming all your Appointment "Private Appointments" and type all details in the appointment body itself.

visit the Outlook user voice forum: https://outlook.uservoice.com/ to submit your ideas

Another Workaround I can think of is to mark items as private and then click File > Print > Print Options > Hide Details of private appointments.

So every time when you want to take a screenshot, just go to the print preview page. Outlook will show "Private appointment".

[image]

Comment: I like where you are going but neither of these ideas would work. Naming all events Private just defeats the point of having a calendar at all; I can't mark events as private because some of these calendars *are* actually shared with *other* people. Further ideas?

Comment: Hope someone else may have a better idea...you can also submit your idea to Outlook uservoice

Answer (score 0):

Could possibly use what is offered here: https://www.canr.msu.edu/news/adding-your-calendar-availability-to-an-email-in-outlook

In essence, you can add your calendar to an email (new email>inset>calendar; and choose the duration, etc.), so you can have what you want this way and share with others; or you could open the attachment (which is generated when doing above), and get a screenshot of that.